# Compile multiple key content from JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

I work in Python, I have data stored in JSON format. 
I want to compile all data that correspond to a certain key. Eg.

```
{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}
```

Where I want to compile the content of all "label" keys into a list.

Is there a way to do this without "going down the tree", that is without having to iterate over the containing keys ("menu" >> "item" >> "label")?

Preferably, I'm looking for a JSON-based solution, and not a trick using REGEX to locate the content.

Comment: No, you'll have to *"go down the tree"*. `[item['label'] for item in tree['menu']['items']]` doesn't seem like so much pain, though.

Comment: JSON-based solution? JSON is a data format, not code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonpath_rw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw):

```
import json
from jsonpath_rw import parse

d = json.loads("""{"menu": {
        "header": "SVG Viewer",
        "items": [
            {"id": "Open"},
            {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
            null,
            {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
            {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
            {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
            null,
            {"id": "Quality"},
            {"id": "Pause"},
            {"id": "Mute"},
            null,
            {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
            {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
            {"id": "Copy"},
            {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
            {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
            {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
            null,
            {"id": "Help"},
            {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
        ]
    }}""")

    get_labels = parse("menu.items[*].label")

    for match in get_labels.find(d):
        print match.value   # value of label
```

Note that this basically does the "go down the tree" for you but its higher-level interface makes it easier to use.